# GEOADD command with Redigo

Tags: go, redis, redigo

Here's what i'm trying, using Redigo ("github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis") :

```
insertPos := []string{"3.361389", "38.115556", "12"}
if _, err := conn.Do("GEOADD", redis.Args{}.Add("geoIndex").AddFlat(&insertPos)...); err != nil {
    log.Print(err)
} 
==> "ERR wrong number of arguments for 'geoadd' command"
```

While with the redis-cli this works fine :

```
GEOADD geoIndex  3.361389  38.115556  12
==> (integer) 1
```

Other commands works fine, that's just the first time I've to use GEOADD and it clearly doesn't seem to work as I expect it to. 
Does someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to call this API is:

```
_, err := conn.Do("GEOADD", "geoIndex", "3.361389", "38.115556", "12")
```

You can also pass number values:

```
_, err := conn.Do("GEOADD", "geoIndex", 3.361389, 38.115556, 12)
```

If you do want to piece the command together, then pass the slice to AddFlat, not a pointer to the slice:

```
insertPos := []string{"3.361389", "38.115556", "12"}
_, err := conn.Do("GEOADD", redis.Args{}.Add("geoIndex").AddFlat(insertPos)...)
```

Comment: You're right, your suggestions were my first tries but I just did a minimal example and it works fine. The problem came in fact from another redis call right after this one which was failing in the case this one was passing... Thanks